# In python Dipslaty an error message until the user enters a name of the proper length

Tags: python

This is for my assignment. I need a help with the "if" code to make sure that the length is between 3 and 20 inclusive
So far I can think of:

```
iEr = True

while iEr:
name = input("please enter your name: ")
if len(name) >= 3:
    iEr = False
else:
    print("Please enter name whose length is between 3 and 20 inclusive")

print("Hi, " + name)
```

I wonder is there a way to correct my "if len(name)" in range 3~20
I know for many people this properly easy, but for me it's hard to think in machine language.
Thank you. :(

Comment: Couple ways you can play around with, put an if statement in your if statement, look up the `and` keyword, or do it in the exact same way you'd write it when writing it in a math equation on paper

Comment: it runs, but my education program doesn't like it much.
Is there other ways you can show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can experiment with to build upon what you know

```
if len(name) >= 3:
     if len(name) <= 20:
```

```
if len(name) >= 3 and len(name) <= 20:
```

```
if 3 <= len(name) <= 20:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if len(name) in range(3,21):`